# Close existing window and open new window and pass the ID on anchor tag click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an anchor tag which opens a window `onclick` then in the window opened I have a table which has a column with an anchor tag as well.

Here's what I've been trying do

Code for anchor tag

```
function handleClickregion() {
  var dropDown = document.getElementById('datestart');
  var branding = document.getElementById('txtbxbrandid').value;
  var dropValue = dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].value;
  event.preventDefault();
  window.open('pages/modals.php?param=' + dropValue + '&param2=' +  branding + '&action=' + 2,'mywindow','directories=no,width=1100,height=500,resizable=yes')
}

<a href="#" id="detailswindow" onclick="handleClickregion()">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span> Details
</a>
```

Then in the modals.php I have a table which is show below (this is opened in a separate window, just a note)

[image]

Then when I click the Details I need to close the `modals.php` window and then open another window which passes the `member_id` to the new window.

How will I do that?

I managed to write a little code but it doesn't open a new modal but closese the previous.

If I do this, it closes the window but does not open a new one (modals2.php)

```
function closeandopennext() {
  window.close('pages/modals.php');
  window.open('pages/modals2.php?param=' + dropValue + '&param2=' +  branding + '&action=' + 4,'mywindow','directories=no,width=1100,height=500,resizable=yes');
}
```

And I interchange the position it does not close the window at all and neither opens a new one

```
function closeandopennext() {
  window.open('pages/modals2.php?param=' + dropValue + '&param2=' +  branding + '&action=' + 4,'mywindow','directories=no,width=1100,height=500,resizable=yes');
  window.close('pages/modals.php');
}
```

Comment: Assuming you are trying to create modal windows you need to use something like http://jquery.iceburg.net/jqModal/#examples.  Window.close and .open will perform as you have found, by closing current and opening new windows - possibly in same window or possibly in another depending on the syntax used.  Using a modal library such as in the link, you can show a 'real' modal window which can be a different URL, so the code you have developed so far will most likely work with little change needed. There are many other modal libraries.

Comment: Did  you check for any console errors? Sounds like something wrong with your `window.open('pages/modals2.php` line.

Comment: Also can you give the HTML for `<a>` which calls `closeandopennext()` function

Answer (score 0):

This works so far so good. Hope you this help you!

```js
var app = app || {};

app.open = function(){
  app.current = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=100");
  app.current.document.write("<input type='button' onClick='javascript:opener.call(100)' value='close' />" );
}

window.call = function(params){
  
  app.current.close();
  app.current = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=100");
  app.current.document.write("<p> I receive param " + params); 
}
```

```html
<button onclick="open()">Open</button>
```